# how to extract info from JWT token?

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

This is how my token is generated:

```js
const generate_web_token = function (user) {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      _id: user._id,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
    },
    process.env.SECRET_TOKEN_KEY
  );
  return token;
};
```

Now, when the clients sends a request to the server, how can the server extract the `_id` field for example?

Comment: Use one of the functions listed in the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Answer (score 4):

The header and claims are just (url-safe) base64 encoded. Only the signature is encrypted and encoded. So you could just split it on the `.` and decode the middle part as those are the claims.

```js
const jwt = `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`

const claims = atob(jwt.split('.')[1])

console.log(claims)
```

You can read more about tokens here https://jwt.io/.

Since you are using a library to handle the tokens for you, it would be probably best to use its features to do that.

```js
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
// some time later
var decodedClaims = jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh');
console.log(decodedClaims.foo) // bar
```